# Firestore Rule - Querying a document field without exposing the whole collection

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a `users` collection which has documents containing various fields. Each document ID is the firebase user ID and the fields hold user data.

I am using the following rule:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
  // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user document.
  match /users/{userId} {
    allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
  }
}
```

Users can select "favourite songs" which are saved within an array field. I now have a requirement to query the database for users which have added a certain songs to their favorites. I created the following query:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = db.collection("users");
usersRef.whereArrayContains("favouriteSongs", "id_of_song");
```

When the query is run the following error is returned:

> com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I obviously need to alter my Firestore rule to allow a user to query the "favouriteSongs" field; however, I do not want to expose all user data to everyone.

Is there a way to expose the "favouriteSongs" data (which only holds IDs) and ensure the rest of the user collection is restricted from being read?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to expose only part of a document to a user, then DarkNeuron's answer is correct. I'm just wonder if you aren't actually for [how to securely query data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly no, security rules are on document/query level. So if a security rule allows access, then the user will have access to the entire document.

If `favouriteSongs` is the only field that can/should be read publicly, then that field should be in a different document.

There are several options. You could have a root level collection called `favoriteSongs` with user documents in it only containing the public data. This would give you the flexibility to easily look up a user's favorites, or query across all the data to find how many users like a particular song.

I recommend that only the user itself can read it's own document, with regards to privacy etc (maybe GDPR if relevant).